# Scrapy não consegue selecionar um form usando xpath

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Olá, estou utilizando o scrapy para fazer um crawler para conseguir pegar questões de concuros e etc do site gabarite.com.br, eu consigo pegar a descrição da pergunta a alternativa correta, porém não consigo pegar a alternativas sempre que executo no terminal o retorno das alternativas e nulo, não sei como proceder poderiam me ajudar?

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
        import scrapy
        import re
        from enemGrabData.items import EnemgrabdataItem
        class MultipleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
            name = 'multiple'
            allowed_domains = ['www.gabarite.com.br']
            start_urls = ['http://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes-de-concursos/disciplina/1-portugues']
            # html body div.site div#content
            def parse(self, response):

                conteudo = response.xpath('//*[@id="content_questoes_conteudo"]')
                item = EnemgrabdataItem();
                for questao in conteudo.xpath('ul'):
                    item['pergunta'] = questao.xpath('li[4]/text()').extract()
                    item['alternativa_A'] = questao.xpath('form/li/fieldset').extract()
                    # //*[@id="content_questoes_conteudo"]/ul[10]/form/li/fieldset
                    item['alternativa_B'] = questao.xpath('/form/li/fieldset/label[2]/text()').extract()
                    item['alternativa_C'] = questao.xpath('/form/li/fieldset/label[3]/text()').extract()
                    item['alternativa_D'] = questao.xpath('/form/li/fieldset/label[4]/text()').extract()
                    item['alternativa_E'] = questao.xpath('/form/li/fieldset/label[5]/text()').extract()
                    item['alternativaCorreta'] = questao.xpath('//form/button/@onclick').extract()
                    inputString = str(item['alternativaCorreta']).split("checaquestao",1)[1]
                    item['alternativaCorreta'] = str(inputString).split(',')[1]

                    # re.findall(r"\(u'(.*?)',\)", inputString)[0]
                       yield item
```

---

```
    <ul>
            <li class="numero"><h3>Questão 5104. &nbsp; <a href="questoes-de-concursos/disciplina/1-portugues">Português</a> - Nível Superior - Polícia Militar GO - UEG - 2013</h3></li>

                <li><a style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:10px; display:inline-block;" onclick="onoff('teste5104')"><img src="imagem/texto-questao.gif" alt="Texto anexado à questão" width="10" height="10"> Texto anexado à questão</a></li>
                <li class="texto" style="display:none;margin-top:5px;" id="teste5104"> <img width="680" height="754" alt="Violência no Brasil, outro olhar" src="http://www.gabarite.com.br/midia/questoes/689-texto.fw.png"></li>

            <li class="pergunta">A expressão “tais como” (linha 3) tem, no texto, a função de introduzir uma
    </li>
            <form name="form-questoes"> 

                <li class="questao">
                    <fieldset>
                    <span><input id="a5104" type="radio" name="radio5104" value="a"></span><label for="a5104">a) concessão</label>
                    <span><input id="b5104" type="radio" name="radio5104" value="b"></span><label for="b5104">b) exemplificação</label>
                    <span><input id="c5104" type="radio" name="radio5104" value="c"></span><label for="c5104">c) conclusão</label>
                    <span><input id="d5104" type="radio" name="radio5104" value="d"></span><label for="d5104">d) exceção</label>        

                    </fieldset>
                </li>
                <button title="Gabarito com resposta certa." name="botao5104" class="btn" type="button" onclick="checaquestao(5104,'b','mult-escolha')">Resolver questão</button>   

            <span id="msg5104"></span>  
            </form> 
            <li class="comentario">
        <ul>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Explique esta questão!" href="javascript:abre_janela('http://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes-de-concursos/questao/5104',500,600)">Comentar questão</a></li>   
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Comentários sobre a questão!" href="javascript:abre_janela('http://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes-de-concursos/questao/5104',500,600)">0 comentários</a></li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Gabarito errado, está desatualizada, foi anulada pela banca, problemas na formatação, etc..." href="javascript:abre_janela('http://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes_aviso.asp?id_questao=5104',500,600)">Notificar erro</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que este exemplo seja útil para você. Não abordei todos os casos possíveis. Há questões de certo e errado que não cheguei a testar. Mas como o seu problema era pegar as alternativas, este exemplo deve lhe dar uma boa idéia de como prosseguir. A identificação da última página está baseada na não existência do botão 'Última'. É uma verificação meio fraca mas serve como exemplo.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import html


def parse(tree):
    conteudo = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content_questoes_conteudo"]')[0]
    forms = conteudo.xpath('form')
    for idx, questao in enumerate(conteudo.xpath('ul')):
        item = {}
        if len(questao.xpath('li[@class="numero"]')):
            item['questao'] = questao.xpath('li[@class="numero"]')[0].text_content()

        if len(questao.xpath('li[@class="texto"]')):
            item['texto'] = questao.xpath('li[@class="texto"]')[0].text_content()

        if len(questao.xpath('li[@class="pergunta"]')):
            item['pergunta'] = questao.xpath('li[@class="pergunta"]')[0].text_content()

        alternativas = forms[idx].xpath('li/fieldset/label')

        item['alternativa_A'] = alternativas[0].text if len(alternativas) > 0 else ''
        item['alternativa_B'] = alternativas[1].text if len(alternativas) > 1 else ''
        item['alternativa_C'] = alternativas[2].text if len(alternativas) > 2 else ''
        item['alternativa_D'] = alternativas[3].text if len(alternativas) > 3 else ''
        item['alternativa_E'] = alternativas[4].text if len(alternativas) > 4 else ''

        item['alternativaCorreta'] = forms[idx].xpath('button/@onclick')[0]
        inputString = str(item['alternativaCorreta']).split("checaquestao", 1)[1]
        item['alternativaCorreta'] = str(inputString).split(',')[1]

        yield item


template_url = "http://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes-de-concursos/?id_materia={}&id_categoria=&nivel=&orgao=&assunto=&pagina={}"

possui_mais_paginas = True
pagina_atual = 1
id_materia = 1  # portugues

while possui_mais_paginas:
    possui_mais_paginas = False  # chuta que é a ultima pagina

    tree = html.parse(template_url.format(id_materia, pagina_atual))

    for item in parse(tree):
        print(item['alternativa_A'].strip())

    encontrou_botao_ultima = False
    for link in tree.xpath('//*[@id="content_paginacao"]/a'):
        if 'Última' in link.text:
            possui_mais_paginas = True  # se não é a ultima página vai para a proxima
            pagina_atual += 1
```

Comment: Como eu poderia dizer ao agoritimo para ir a proxima página, no scrapy e feito com duas linhas, tentei nesse código que você me passou importando as libs mas não deu certo ate agora

Comment: Editei para incluir a paginação e a passagem de parâmetros como, matéria. Espero que ajude. De qualquer forma, você também pode editar seu código no scrapy e incluir as consultas xpath que utillizei no meu. Deve funcionar talvez com pequenas adaptações.

Comment: Consegui através do seu exemplo deu para fazer usando o scrapy, obrigado pela ajuda, se quiser ver como ficou deixo o link https://github.com/jpaulo789b/Crawler-Quest-es-Enem/blob/master/indo/spiders/spiderquestoes.py